# My Node.js backend doesn't connect with a MySQL service in a VPS

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection, vps

I have a problem here.... I hope you can help me....

I'm developing a Flutter Chat App using a Node.js backend with a MySQL database.
In development environment....everything goes OK...but in the VPS environment, the Node.js Code can't connect with the MySQL service and I can't find what is going on!!....

The Server throw me the next log

```
Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/data/Jasper/SERVER_BTN95/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
  parent:
   { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
       at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/data/Jasper/SERVER_BTN95/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:189:17)
       at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
       at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
       at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
     errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     syscall: 'connect',
     fatal: true },
  original:
   { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
       at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/data/Jasper/SERVER_BTN95/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:189:17)
       at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
       at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
       at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
     errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     syscall: 'connect',
     fatal: true } }
(node:3270005) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Server.<anonymous> (/data/Jasper/SERVER_BTN95/models/server.js:58:23)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/data/Jasper/SERVER_BTN95/models/server.js:6:65)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:3270005) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3270005) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

and this is my connection code:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const sequelize_1 = require("sequelize");


const db = new sequelize_1.Sequelize('cw', 'root', 'mypass', {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: '/*I put here my VPS IP but I don’t know if I have to put 10.0.0.2 or localhost*/',
    port: my_port,
        multipleStatements : true
});


db.authenticate()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
        });


process.on('unhandledRejection', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    // sendInTheCalvary(err);
});


exports.default = db;
```

Seriously... I hope you can help me...'cause I having this problem for a while... And I come here 'cause I don't know what more to do.... and.... Sorry about my English.... I'm a Spanish speaker...!!

I tried add

```
const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    throw new Error('Promise 1 has tanked.');
});

const promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    promise1.then();
});

(async function() {
    try {
        await promise2;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})();
```

to my code... but anything happend

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: (`Spanish speaker` are you aware of [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)?)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was my mistake that I was working with the wrong port when connecting to the MySQL server. I was using the port from the project (development env) which was the default MySQL 3306 port.